# Django UpdateView get_context_data function called twice

Tags: django

Here is the thing:
  I have two models - Group and Storage.And I want to update the data.But my model Group can update my data,and my model Storage can't.So I debug my code,and find the reason why my Storage data can't update: the funtion get_context_data() called twice.Once on the page load,Twice on the form post.But function form_valid isn't called.
  All same code,but different result.Someone can tell me why this happen？
  Thanks

Code:

```
class Group(models.Model):
  id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
  info=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
class Storage(models.Model):
  id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  disk_size=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
  disk_path=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
  info=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")

class ManagerStorageUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
  model = models.Storage
  form_class = forms.StorageCreateUpdateForm
  template_name = 'new_update_storage.html'
  success_url = reverse_lazy('manager:storage')

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ManagerStorageUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    hosts = models.Host.objects.all()
    storage_hosts = [host.id for host in self.object.hosts.all()]
    context.update({
        'hosts':hosts,
        'storage_hosts':storage_hosts
    })
    return context

  def form_valid(self, form):
    host_storage = form.save()
    hosts_id_list = self.request.POST.getlist('hosts',[])
    hosts = models.Host.objects.filter(id__in=hosts_id_list)
    host_storage.hosts.clear()
    host_storage.hosts.add(*hosts)
    host_storage.save()
    return super(ManagerStorageUpdateView,self).form_valid(form)

  def get_success_url(self):
    return self.success_url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `form_valid()` isn't called that means your form has some errors. You may want to display those on the page.
And most likely this is the reason its calling `get_context_data()` for POST request as well.

Comment: Thanks.I recode that UpdateView of Storage.Always same code,and it work.Maybe some problem with my form_valid().Tab or Space or something.